# How to set IE 11 enterprise mode to standard mode using javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I tried a lot for Ckeditor not working when I changed IE 11 standard  to Enterprise mode.

I have set below in header for document mode but it does not seems:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

So I have substituted idea to turn off the enterprise mode while the page being load but i did not get any javascript code to turn off mode while page load.

Please suggest if any idea to turn off Enterprise mode using java script it would be great helpful.

Comment: Can you expand why you need `IE=8`?  also by " Ckeditor not working" what do you mean? any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't thinkg you will be able to disable a Group Policy, Local Policy, Reg Setting using JS

Comment: @atmd I am working on CKeditor integrating with the php page but , the issue is CKeditor does not load on IE11 enterprise mode?if i changed to standard that has been working fine. could you please suggest how could i resolve the issue in iE11 enterprise mode?.

Comment: are you getting console errors?

Comment: First off, you cannot disable EMIE through JavaScript.  Second, when you right-click the page and check properties, what zone is the page loading in?  If not Internet, then you need to either disable the compatibility setting that automatically loads intranet pages into compatibility view or you need to add a mark of the web to load the page in the Internet zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used TinyMCE editor instead of Ckeditor it has been worked fine.

Then i could used the meta header below tag:

```
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9,IE=7">
```

Still the TinyMCE completable with All IE browser.